$_POST variables empty after send with jquery ajax
This form was working till jan/24. Now, all variables are empty on my $_POST.
Here is my code:
HTML:
<form id="main-schedule-form" name="schedule-form" method="post" action="sendemailschedule.php">                            
    <label for="nome">Nome*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="name" required/>
    <label for="email">E-mail*</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Enviar</button>
</form> 

Jquery:
var form = $('#main-schedule-form');
form.submit(function(event) {
   var str = $(this).serialize(); // when I console.log it, the content is right
   $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      type: "POST",
      data: str,
   }).done(function(data) {
      $('#main-schedule-form')[0].reset();
      alert("Thanks!");
   });
});

PHP:
<?php
    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $email= @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
    ...

when I print $name and $email, it gets empty. When I var_dump($_POST), I receive an empty array.
What do I miss?

How and where are you observing this output? There's nothing in your jquery code which would allow you to see it, and of course from an ajax request it will not update your page automatically

If you eliminate the jQuery part and just post your HTML for to sendemailschedule.php does it work? Did something change on your server on Jan 24?

P.s. no idea why you think you need to use stripslashes on these data items in the php? What are you trying to achieve with that? The use cases for it are small and generally unusual

name=JOHN+DOE&email=jdoe%40gmail.com is what I get when console.log(str)
array(0) {
} is what I receive when var_dump($_POST)
I treid to remove trim and stripslashes, but still not working

I realized that $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] is returning GET, but I dont know why

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); This smells like SQL injection.

As it turns out, there was an issue in .htaccess that prevented this from working. .htaccess does not change the request method, so if it was due to something in the .htaccess, then it must have been a redirect to a GET request.
Your request type is indeed set to POST and you indeed pass the parameters correctly, this is why it was working up to pretty recently.


var form = $('#main-schedule-form');
form.submit(function(event) {
   var str = $(this).serialize(); // when I console.log it, the content is right
   console.log(str);
   $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      type: "POST",
      data: str,
   }).done(function(data) {
      $('#main-schedule-form')[0].reset();
      alert("Thanks!");
   });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="main-schedule-form" name="schedule-form" method="post" action="sendemailschedule.php">                            
    <label for="nome">Nome*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="name" required/>
    <label for="email">E-mail*</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Enviar</button>
</form>



So, it's important to realize that .htaccess does redirects. If you watch the Network tab of your browser's dev tools, then you should see these parameters being properly passed to a POST request, just like you expected. So it's not your Javascript nor your PHP that was to blame, but some erroneous changes on your htaccess.

The problem was on my .htaccess. The $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] was returning GET because of it

Sounds like it was doing a redirect of the request? Your answer should include precisely what you did to fix the issue, otherwise it's not much use to other people who might have a similar problem! See also [answer]. You can [edit] your answer to update it - thanks.
